# Properties Dialog Box not appearing when uploading a document to a document library

Tags: document-library, file-upload

I am creating a site on SharePoint 2010.  I have created a document library and want users to be prompted to enter information into required columns when they upload a file.  I have:

- Enabled "Allow management of content types?" under Advanced settings
- Changed the settings for some columns in the "Document" content type to required

I would expect now that when a user uploads a document to the document library they would be prompted to enter the required fields.

Instead the document is uploaded and checked in without any prompts.  When I select the document and click "Edit Properties" I cannot save the document until the required columns are entered.  This is exactly the behavior I want to occur when the documents are first uploaded.

From doing extensive Google searches on the subject this should be working based on the settings above.

[image][image]

Comment: Add "Document" as the default content type. Are you using custom columns as required fields?

Comment: I am utilizing custom columns in other parts of the site but I have set up a test Document Library that is very simple.  The "Document" content type is the default and Title, Company columns are both set to required.  I am editing my original post with some screenshots.